# Updating Android Applications That Come Installed on Your Phone

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play

I have an android application APK that has been burnt in the android OS. So it becomes its native application. So can you please guide me how I remove it after OS burnt on the phone. If I cant remove it without root access. Can I update this native application by any way. It is not uploaded on Google Play. So can I do this that I can upload its newer version on Google Play Store and then update manually from device android market/play store application?

Please guide me if this option is valid or not. If yes then How? And If No then how can I achieve this.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stack Overflow as it is not about programming. You would probably have better luck asking on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. You would probably have better luck asking on android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @2Dee Sorry about the dupe comment, automatic with custom close reason. I thought your explanation was good.

Comment: @thegrinner, no problem at all ;-)

Comment: One more thing guys if you dont have any answer for this question than close your browser. Dont't downvote the question.

Comment: Downvote = "This question does not show any research effort[it is the case here];it is unclear or not useful[again, it's the case here, since SO is for programming, not end user support]" ...

Comment: Marcin Orlowski gives me good answer for that question. It is programming question.

Answer (score 3):

> been burnt in the android OS

No. It's only installed on (by default) read-only partition.

> So can you please guide me how I remove it after OS burnt on the phone

You need write access to that partition => root

> Can I update this native application by any way

Yes. Just install any new app with **the same package id and singed with the same certificate** the ROM-installed version is and you got it updated

Comment: when I try to manually download its newer version from sd card. It shows that application can not be installed..